# International targeting with a single language

Tags: seo, internationalization, geotargeting, hreflang, international

I was going through tons of documentation, forums, stackoverflow, etc trying to figure out what is the correct way to target international audience with a single language. The only thing that I could find is to use country/region specific TLDs. However, when I setup headers got international targeting as:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="mx" href="alternateURL">
```

I am forced to declare another language. In our case, target international market with English is part of business model, so there is no reason for us to invest for translations.

I know that is it possible, the question is how?

Comment: I am confused. Sorta. .Com TLDs and the like penetrate all countries while a ccTLD will only penetrate those countries where there is interest and common languages. Since your site is English, wouldn't a .com be the ticket??

Comment: Here is the real catch that I forgot to mention. We don't have .com , we only own rTLDs. They also considered general in most cases, but as far as I understand targeting with specific region is better. The real question at this point what tags do I need to set in such case?

Comment: Is there any difference at all between these sites? (I'm assuming you have  multiple sites with different ccTLDs?) A ccTLD domain doesn't necessarily make it less relevant in a search in another country - it will depend on your content.

Comment: We are planning to have multiple whitelabels under different rTLDs (at least for the close future). Generally the content is the same, it's some if the branding and design that will be different.

Comment: - "*I am forced to declare another language.*" - How exactly are you forced to declare another language? What's stopping you from simply declaring your single language with `hreflang="your language" href="your url"`?

Comment: @ArtenGR - You should not use a single hreflang tag, so that would not be valid.